Is it possible to disable certain commands in powershell for a group of users?
I am trying to find out if it is possible to disable certain command-lets in Powershell for a group of users.
The use case is to only enable ps-remote from a jumphost for most of the users. These users must not be able to run any other command-lets or scripts on the jumphost itself.
I have looked into GPO for disabling enabling the powershell as well as execution policy. None of these really fit my use case.
I had been investigating powershell profiles as well, but i am not sure if something can be done there.

It is not possible. If you allow an unprivileged user to run a PowerShell console then you allow unprivileged PowerShell commands.

Find a way to have Admin run the PS script, not the user. Perhaps as a scheduled task, as a service, etc.

Yes, with "Windows" this is possible for portions of your requirements 100% on a Windows Server OS. You have not specified which Windows OS you are referring to. Start your reading and research here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/security/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-7.4 and check and read over the posts linked to from it. I assume will not work Windows 10 or 11 though. You should be able to set WSMan for only the "trusted hosts" you allow to connect to it, and then from it allow on the cmdlets you want then to run, etc. trivial from there if this suffices.
